# Inserting fields to MySQL Database through PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert values from gravity form submissions into mysql database using php, but nothing is showing up in my database when I try it:

Here is my code:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_17", "push_fields", 10, 2);

function push_fields($entry, $form){
    $title = $entry[1];
    $location = $entry[1];
    global $connection;
    $query = ("INSERT INTO events(title, location) VALUES ($title, $location)");
    $result = $connection->query($query);
}
```

I have already connected to the database, as I have used other functions that are pulling data already in the database:

```
$servername = '127.0.0.1';
$username = '*******';
$password = '*******';
$dbname = '*******';
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other info you need.

EDITED (TO TEST FOR ERRORS):

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_17", "input_fields", 10, 2);
function add_entry($entry){
   $title = mysql_real_escape_string($entry[1]);
   $location = mysql_real_escape_string($entry[2]);
   global $connection;
   $query = ("INSERT INTO events(title, location) VALUES ('$title' , '$location')");
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
   if($result){
       echo 'Query OK';
   }else{
       echo 'Query failed';
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you added error checking to see if $results is actually working or if it's failing and giving an error message?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @StevenByrne. I edited my code above to test for errors. It's showing the result is working, but looking through my database, it is either not showing up or showing up occasionally with none of the fields filled in with my submissions.

Comment: Does it add an empty row, or no row at all? Maybe try echoing out the values you intent to insert before inserting them

Comment: It adds an empty row, and echoing the values doesn't show anything

Comment: Well, there's your answer; some how the args are being lost, has nothing to do with MySQL; I'm not sure where to look from there as I'm not familiar with your code but if you adjust the quest we might be able to help; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This may be unhelpful if you're deliberately connecting to the DB; however, you might consider using the GFAPI.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#add-entry